# Bandcamp embeded player look blurry

Tags: audio, embed, media-player

i put iframe of Bandcamp embeded player on my website, but the background-image of my track look blurry.
i made this cover in Illustrator in 2400x2400 and i exported in Png24.. When i look the background image in Bandcamp the image seems in good quality.. i dont understand what to do to view the cover in my website in good quality.
you can see it in https://mauditemachine.com/

i tried to see what happened if i change the background-image to 1 instead of 8
`<div id="art" class="item" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a2126636077_8.jpg&quot;);"></div>`
i see a better quality but i cant force it..

when i tried to change the size to 400x400 in the iframe code i have better results but i want to have 300x300 sizing.

Answer (score 0):

i just change iframe parameters to select 100% for width and height.
In my Css i put width and height to 400px to a container above and for responsive design i put 300px